# Loading Text From Webpage and Sorting It

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to load the data from the link that ill post below and sort through it and output all of it via string.split, but it was all working until i added a new row, now it wont load the new row, but it does load the rest. Heres the code and link , i been trying things for several hours now and i cant seem to figure out whats wrong.

http://lgdev.site.nfoservers.com/getItems.php

```
IEnumerator loadItems()
{
    WWW w = new WWW("http://lgdev.site.nfoservers.com/getItems.php");
    yield return w;
    string[] tmpdata1 = w.text.Split(char.Parse("/"));
    foreach (string data in tmpdata1)
    {
        Debug.Log(data);
        string[] tmpinfo = data.Split(char.Parse("~"));
        GameObject tmpObj = Instantiate(Resources.Load("weapon", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
        tmpObj.transform.SetParent(transform);
        gearList.Add(tmpObj);
        tmpObj.name = tmpinfo[0] + "-gear";
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().name = tmpinfo[0];
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().vitalisim = int.Parse(tmpinfo[1]);
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().defence = int.Parse(tmpinfo[2]);
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().strength = int.Parse(tmpinfo[3]);
        string[] offsetInfo1 = tmpinfo[5].Split(char.Parse(";"));
        foreach (string off in offsetInfo1)
        {
            string[] offset = off.Split(char.Parse(","));
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().offsetsPos.Add(new Vector3(float.Parse(offset[0]), float.Parse(offset[1]), float.Parse(offset[2])));
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().offetsRot.Add(new Vector3(float.Parse(offset[3]), float.Parse(offset[4]), float.Parse(offset[5])));
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().offetsSize.Add(new Vector3(float.Parse(offset[6]), float.Parse(offset[7]), float.Parse(offset[8])));
        }

        string[] offsetInfo2 = tmpinfo[8].Split(char.Parse(";"));
        foreach (string off in offsetInfo2)
        {
            string[] offset = off.Split(char.Parse(","));
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().sheathedOffsetsPos.Add(new Vector3(float.Parse(offset[0]), float.Parse(offset[1]), float.Parse(offset[2])));
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().sheathedOffsetsRot.Add(new Vector3(float.Parse(offset[3]), float.Parse(offset[4]), float.Parse(offset[5])));
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().sheathedOffsetsSize.Add(new Vector3(float.Parse(offset[6]), float.Parse(offset[7]), float.Parse(offset[8])));
        }

        string[] typeInfo = tmpinfo[4].Split(char.Parse(","));
        if (typeInfo.Length == 2)
        {
            if (typeInfo[1] == "SwordnShield")
            {
                tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().anim = swordAndShieldAnimSet;
            }
            else if (typeInfo[1] == "TwoHanded")
            {
                tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().anim = twoHandedAnimSet;
            }
        }
        foreach (string prefab in tmpinfo[6].Split(char.Parse(",")))
        {
            tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().prefabs.Add("Gear"+"/"+typeInfo[0]+"/"+ prefab);
        }

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string bone in tmpinfo[7].Split(char.Parse(",")))
        {
            i = 0;
            foreach (string boneName in GetComponent<boneManager>().boneStrings)
            {
                if (bone == boneName)
                {
                    tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().rootbones.Add(GetComponent<boneManager>().bones[i]);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        i = 0;
        foreach (string bone in tmpinfo[9].Split(char.Parse(",")))
        {
            if (System.Array.IndexOf(GetComponent<boneManager>().boneStrings, bone) >= 0)
            {
                tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().sheathedRootbones.Add(GetComponent<boneManager>().bones[i]);
            }
        }

        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().type = typeInfo[0];
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().spawnInModels();
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().hubAnimator = hubAnimator;
        tmpObj.GetComponent<gear>().UnEquip();
    }
    gear = gearList.ToArray();

    if (PhotonNetwork.room.name == "Hub")
    {
        gear[currentWep].GetComponent<gear>().Sheathe();
        gear[currentBody].GetComponent<gear>().Sheathe();
        gear[currentLegs].GetComponent<gear>().Sheathe();
        gear[currentWep].GetComponent<gear>().Sheathe();
    }
    else
    {
        gear[currentWep].GetComponent<gear>().Equip();
        gear[currentBody].GetComponent<gear>().Equip();
        gear[currentLegs].GetComponent<gear>().Equip();
        gear[currentWep].GetComponent<gear>().Equip();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving the new data at all? (Maybe its displaying cached version). Test with this to avoid caching `WWW w = new WWW("http://lgdev.site.nfoservers.com/getItems.php?r="+Random.value*9999);`

Comment: Yeah, like i said it prints everything but the last row. @mgear